# Am I able todo XML and MYSQL Together?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

hope you all ok.

What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
$url = "URL";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$user=$xml->user->user;

if ($xml->user->user == 'ABC')
{
  ABIT OF TEXT
} elseif ($xml->user->user != 'ABC')
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ABC";
  ECHO ABIT OF TEXT
} else 
{
  NOTHING MATCHES USE THIS TEXT
}
```

Ok people dont even try and use that code on a website as it wont work but now you can see what i mean ill give a little text version:

A search will be done on a URL that is XML the XML will have data as we see here the ->user if this is == to the username ABC to get a bit of text.

now if after the XML search the user is != to ABC I would like/need it to jump into a mysql database to try and find the user ABC if the user is in the MYSQL database then we have the "ECHO ABIT OF TEXT".

then finally if neither the XML or MYSQL matches i have a 3rd section of text to use.

please remember that i fully understand the code above is by far from working format but its there as a visual ref to what im asking.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible to first check the values of the xml and if it does not contain what you want to then check the database (the else doesn't make sense as you are only checking if 'ABC' in the xml or not, there is no third option). What is your actual question?

Comment: yes sorry reading it back myself i didnt word it very good hahah let me try again:

If ABC matches from the XML = Show Text 1

if ABC dosnt match the XML search a MYSQL Database if ABC is in the database then = Show Text 2

If Neither the XML or Database = Show Text 3

My Question is how do i get the code to switch between looking at the XML URL to looking at my MYSQL Database?? i hope this words better

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define a variable to 'catch' the results of your checks on the xml and the database. It could be something like `$userFound = false;` and then setting it true if the user is in the database or xml.

In this snippet I simply use the `$text` variable which gets defined as `null`, but filled with text when the user is in xml or db. In the if-constructs I just check if it is still null -> has not been found yet.

```
$url = "URL";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$user=$xml->user->user;
$text = null;

if ($user == 'ABC')
{
  $text = 'ABIT OF TEXT';
}
if ($text === null)
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ABC";
  $text = 'ABIT OF TEXT';
} 
if ($text === null)
{
  $text = 'NOTHING MATCHES USE THIS TEXT';
}
echo $text;
```